# swig python derived and base in different modules

Tags: python, inheritance, swig

I am trying to reproduce a python example from the swig 4.0 documentation [Modules Basics](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Modules.html#Modules_nn1). I got properly generated _base_module.so and _derived_module.so . However when I try to use derived module from my test program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import derived_module
...
```

I got an import error:ImportError: /homes/../_derived_module.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI4Base

The reason for the error is quite understandable but it is not clear how to avoid it. Below are my files.

base.h:

```
#ifndef _BASE_H_INCLUDED_
#define _BASE_H_INCLUDED_

class base {
public:
    virtual int foo();
};

#endif // _BASE_H_INCLUDED_
```

base.cpp:

```
#include "base.h"

int base::foo() { return 10; }
```

base_module.i:

```
%module base_module

%{
#include "base.h"
%}
%include base.h
```

derived_module.i:

```
%module derived_module

%{
#include "base.h"
%}

%import(module="base_module") "base.h"

%inline %{
class derived : public base {
public:
    int foo() override { return 20; }
};
%}
```

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import derived_module

if __name__ == "__main__":
    derived = derived_module.derived();
    res = derived.foo();
    print("res={}".format(res));
    sys.exit()
```

Makefile:

```
SWIG = swig4
CCX = g++

LD = g++

all: derived_module.py

derived_module.py: base.h base.cpp base_module.i derived_module.i
        ${SWIG} -python -py3 -c++ -cppext cpp base_module.i
        ${SWIG} -python -py3 -c++ -cppext cpp derived_module.i
        ${CCX} -O2 -fPIC -c base.cpp
        ${CCX} -O2 -fPIC -c base_module_wrap.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.8
        ${CCX} -O2 -fPIC -c derived_module_wrap.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.8
        ${LD} -shared base.o base_module_wrap.o -o _base_module.so
        ${LD} -shared derived_module_wrap.o -o _derived_module.so

run: derived_module.py
        python3 ./test.py

clean:
        rm -rf *~ derived_module.py base_module.py *_wrap.* *.o *.so __pycache__
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I built the "Modules Basics" example. It had some minor errors, but your code is different, so make a [mcve].

Comment: I could reproduce the example module if I do not have .cpp files and implement both derived::bar() and base::foo() functions inline. If I provide .cpp files I will have import errors. My guess that it is enough to have base::foo() inline to avoid import errors.

Comment: Please edit the question with the files that reproduce the problem.

Comment: FYI, I created the two modules with .cpp files instead of inline and it still works for me.  You'll have to make a [mcve] to determine your issue.

Comment: updated the question, in my testing keys to failure (a) derived class implements override of virtual function from base, (b) base implementation non in-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this with your toolchain because I only have MSVC and a Windows system at the moment, but you need to link `base.o` into the derived module as well:

```
${LD} -shared base.o derived_module_wrap.o -o _derived_module.so
```

You may want to make `base.o` into a shared module as well so there is no duplication of code.

It worked both ways for me using MSVC.

Comment: Yes, adding base.o to _derived_module.so worked. It will be nice to update the docs.